# Android Studio LinearLayout gerando erro ao rolar

Tags: android-studio

Saudações,
Minha aplicação android tem um LinearLayout e, dentro dele, um GridView que está sendo preenchido corretamente com as imagens que eu quero.

O problema é que, ao rolar a tela para baixo (para ver o restante dos ícones), os últimos ícones ficam fora de ordem e a rolagem não funciona mais. Só reiniciando o app que o GridView volta a funcionar.

Seguem o código e a tela com o problema:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layScroll"
    android:layout_width="413dp"
    android:layout_height="447dp"
    android:background="@color/branco"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/frmPrincipal"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/frmPrincipal"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grvMain"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:columnWidth="60dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

A Tela boa (assim que abre o app):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A tela ruim (depois que faz o Scroll - coloquei várias imagens iguais para fazer o teste do scroll):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois que faz o Scroll, a tela meio que trava por, pelo menos, 15 segundos e os ícones ficam todos desarrumados dentro do GridView.

Tentei usar o ScrollView também e deu o mesmo erro/resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido.
Após vários dias sem respostas e/ou ajuda, decidi eliminar o Gridview do meu aplicativo e utilizar o CardView e TableLayout

Answer (score -2):

Uma dica, utilize o ScrollView como View Pai, dentro dele use o layout que quiser (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ...), nesse layout coloque suas views.